# Gigabit switch in 10/100 router network

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have a 10/100 router. I bought gigabit switch. One port is connected to routers, others to my home hosts. Speed between hosts is 12mbps.

So, is it possible to have gigabit connection between hosts, connected to gigabit switch, if switch also connected to 100mb router?

Thank's for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do theoretically 1Gbps between any devices as long as they're plugged directly into the gigabit switch and they have Gig NICs (Network Cards).

With networking you're restricted to the weakest link in the path. As long as the router isn't in the path between the host on the network the speed of It's interface won't affect anything else.

Also if you're not seeing what you think you should be seeing you may want to look at the properties on the computer's NIC to see what speed it's autonegotiation is coming up at. A damaged rj-45 cable(ethernet cable) can work fine and 100mbps but not function for a gig connection.

All of this is of course before network overhead and other things along that line.